# MySQL total memory allocated usage? memory leak?

Tags: mysql, memory, memory-management

i'm using 5.6.21-70.0 for performance test.

when i run

> mysqlslap -a --concurrency=40 --number-of-queries 1000 --iterations=500 --engine=innodb --debug-info -utest -p

do some performance test and the ram growth up over the maximum memory usage and never release

when finish mysqlslap
the memory show use 78%

i have a 1G physical memory and and i do **NOT** use **swap**

> KiB Mem:   1016656 total,   953808 used,    62848 free,    30324 buffers
>
> KiB Swap:        0 total,        0 used,        0 free.    41384 cached Mem
>
> PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S %CPU **%MEM**     TIME+ COMMAND
>   26049 mysql     20   0 1544156 778316   3992 S 16.3 **76.6**   6:24.01 mysqld

**it seems like mysqld use about 700M memory? why it over the max memory usage?
and why mysql never release the memory? **

my mysqlturning.pl shows:

> [OK] Highest usage of available connections: 70% (42/60)
>
> [OK] Key buffer size / total MyISAM indexes: 32.0M/98.0K
>
> [--] Reads / Writes: 40% / 60%
>
> [--] Total buffers: 336.0M global + 1.1M per thread (60 max threads)
>
> [OK] Maximum possible memory usage: **403.5M** (40% of installed RAM)

```
----------------------
BUFFER POOL AND MEMORY
----------------------
Total memory allocated 274726912; in additional pool allocated 0
Total memory allocated by read views 96
Internal hash tables (constant factor + variable factor)
    Adaptive hash index 4446416     (4425832 + 20584)
    Page hash           277432 (buffer pool 0 only)
    Dictionary cache    1170261     (1107952 + 62309)
    File system         815920  (812272 + 3648)
    Lock system         665656  (664936 + 720)
    Recovery system     0   (0 + 0)
Dictionary memory allocated 62309
Buffer pool size        16383
Buffer pool size, bytes 268419072
Free buffers            1024
Database pages          15358
Old database pages      5649
Modified db pages       0
Pending reads 0
Pending writes: LRU 0, flush list 0, single page 0
Pages made young 407, not young 484
0.00 youngs/s, 0.00 non-youngs/s
Pages read 614, created 17947, written 20737
0.00 reads/s, 0.00 creates/s, 0.00 writes/s
No buffer pool page gets since the last printout
Pages read ahead 0.00/s, evicted without access 0.00/s, Random read ahead 0.00/s
LRU len: 15358, unzip_LRU len: 0
I/O sum[0]:cur[0], unzip sum[0]:cur[0]
```

my my.cnf----

```
 # Generated by Percona Configuration Wizard (http://tools.percona.com/) version REL5-20120208

 [mysql]

 # CLIENT #
 port                           = 3306
 socket                         = /data/data/mysql.sock

 [mysqld]

 # GENERAL #
 user                           = mysql
 default-storage-engine         = InnoDB
 socket                         = /data/data/mysql.sock
 pid-file                       = /data/data/mysql.pid
 character-set-server=utf8
 collation-server=utf8_general_ci

 # MyISAM #
 key-buffer-size                = 32M
 myisam-recover                 = FORCE,BACKUP

 # SAFETY #
 max-allowed-packet             = 16M
 max-connect-errors             = 1000000
 skip-name-resolve
 sql-mode                       = STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION,NO_ZERO_DATE,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY
 sysdate-is-now                 = 1
 innodb                         = FORCE

 # DATA STORAGE #
 datadir                        = /data/data/

 # BINARY LOGGING #
 log-bin                        = /data/data/mysql-bin
 expire-logs-days               = 14
 sync-binlog                    = 1

 # CACHES AND LIMITS #
 tmp-table-size                 = 32M
 max-heap-table-size            = 32M
 query-cache-type               = 0
 query-cache-size               = 0
 max-connections                = 60
 thread-cache-size              = 50
 open-files-limit               = 65535
 table-definition-cache         = 1024
 table-open-cache               = 2048

 # INNODB #
 innodb-flush-method            = O_DIRECT
 innodb-log-files-in-group      = 2
 innodb-log-file-size           = 64M
 innodb-flush-log-at-trx-commit = 1
 innodb-file-per-table          = 1
 innodb-buffer-pool-size        = 64M

 # LOGGING #
 log-error                      = /data/data/mysql-error.log
 log-queries-not-using-indexes  = 0 # slow will not log the query which do not use index
 long-query-time                = 1
 slow-query-log                 = 1
 slow-query-log-file            = /data/data/mysql-slow.log
```

Answer (score 2):

i have found out why memory leak happeneds.
now i have only 1GB memory and no swap.

the **performance_schema** cause the allocate the memory for about 400M at startup. and innodb will take up to 400M memory usage

so，because of my.cnf use

```
table-definition-cache= 1024
table-open-cache= 2048 
max-connections= 60
```

it will cause high **performance_schema** allocated,
more information pls see

[ref1](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=69665)

[ref2](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=68287)

Answer (score 0):

Try Running `FLUSH TABLES` on InnoDB tables it will close the files against the .ibd files. I hope it will release the memory usages!!

You might be using a 32 bit machine which normally gives around 3G but you are using 40% of the physical memory which is well enough, still I think you need to extend the breath space and you definitely needs to allow buffer size little larger than the size of your data or index pages.

Try using a 64 bit machine and using a swap will allow it to breath more easily including larger size of buffer pool of your data/index size.

Comment: thanks for you post,now i'm using centos 7 64bit machine. "Linux  3.10.0-123.9.3.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Thu Nov 6 15:06:03 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux" and now i am using 1G physical memory

Comment: and FLUSH TABLES does not release the memory usage :( it always keep  77% usage memory of 1GB

Comment: nothing. just an empty database. but i'm using percona-server-5.6.21.i'm not sure if this version mysql has a bug?

Comment: do u have any locked table in ur db?.. I think it no server issue. have a look on optimization http://www.percona.com/resources/technical-presentations/optimizing-mysql-configuration-percona-live-washington-dc-2012 hope it helps

Comment: i have found out why memory leak happeneds. now i have only 1GB memory and no swap. the **performance_schema** cause the allocate the memory for about 400M. and innodb will take up 400M memory so，my.cnf use **table-definition-cache= 1024** **table-open-cache= 2048** **max-connections= 60** calculate performance_schema reserved memory, that means it will cause high **performance_schema** allocated,more information pls see [info1](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=68514) [infor2](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=69665)